# how do i get a clickable URL using POST? HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, localhost

sorry if this is difficult to understand as english is not my first language.

I have made a form using HTML and PHP with localhost, How it works is people enter information such as first and last name, press submit and their questions and awnsers come back in PHP.

On my form i ask people to enter their URL for a project, this comes back as plain text in PHP. What i would like to happen is instead of it coming back in plain text, it comes back as a link, For example if they enter www.google.com, instead of it being plain text, its a link that if clicked on will take you to google. For my example i ask for the users Project URL and PHP responds with your project URL is "Fill in the blank" I will now show my HTML and PHP.

```
HTML: 
<form method="post" action="0308_Assigning_Values.php">

<p>
 Project url:<br />
 <input type="text" name="projecturl" size="30">
</p>


PHP:

<?php

$projecturl = $_POST['projecturl'];


echo "your project url is: <span class='textblue'> $projecturl</span></p> ";

?>
```

Comment: use the [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag : `<a href="<?php echo $projecturl; ?>">Your project url</a>`

Comment: Hello, thank you for response, i entered echo "<a href="<?php echo $projecturl; ?>">Your project url</a>" under my echo shown in the question and got a this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\working\0308_Assigning_Values.php on line 21. Do i simply need to replace my echo with this one? Thankyou. EDIT: i have worked out i just needed to make another <?php under my orginal one. Thankyou.

Comment: Well, yes, if you already are echoing the HTML, don't use another echo inside but concate the strings

Comment: Hello, i was able to get the >Your project url< to become a link! thankyou! but even if i enter a different url, the same one comes up that i entered in PHP. is it possible for them to change based on what i enter?